# How to download files from local pc to remote pc?

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, ssh, azure

I have some files on my local PC and I need to send these files to my Azure machine. Both machines are Ubuntu 16.04 and I know that I can send the data through "Connect to Server" section of the Ubuntu file system GUI (I use SFTP to connect) but that option is too slow. Is there a way to do something like set my local PC as server and "download" the data from remote PC to take the advantage of high download speed of remote PC has?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Your question is not clear. Whether you're "uploading" the file **to** the remote server or you're "dowloading" the file **from** your PC, you're using the **same** _direction_, i.e. the bandwidth available on the _upstream_ side of your connection.

Comment: @MrShunz from my local PC to Azure instance but download process will happen on Azure instance. My local PC will be the data server.

Comment: it doesn't matter. If it's slow uploading it will be slow downloading from the other side. If you have, say, a connection with 1Mbps upload, the server will "download" at 1Mbps from your PC, same as uploading at 1Mbps from your PC to the server.

Comment: @MrShunz I understand now and I feel stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Download* and *upload* refer to the direction the data is travelling in. That means, the *download* speed refers to the speed for data that is transferred *towards* your computer. The *upload* speed refers to the speed for data that is transferred *from* your computer to some place else.

You can image that as a large road with many lanes that leads *to* your house (the download capacity) and a small road with only one lane that leads *away* from your house. Both of these roads are one-way only. You can't use the large road in the inverse direction, and you can't use the small road in the inverse direction.

It's the same with your internet connection: The download capacity can only be used to transfer data *to* your computer, and the upload capacity can only be used to transfer data *from* your computer somewhere else.

Comment: I know how download and upload works but I am the reason of this misunderstanding. Sorry about that. Let's say you are trying to download something using wget or curl or scp. In that case you give a fixed web address which has the data as a parameter to commands I've mentioned. I'm trying to do the same thing but this time my local PC will be the that fixed web address (with IP of course) and this way I can use the download speed of Azure cloud instance.

Comment: @DorukSonmez You’re still missing the point. The speed allowed to go through is determined by the connection parameters (road and lanes in Henning’s metaphor), not by which party initiates the transfer. The lowest limit on the way limits the whole transfer (see [Bottleneck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_bottleneck)).

Comment: @Melebius I understand now. Thank you so much for your explanation and time.